# May I call a virtual function to initialize a base-class sub-object?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual, ctor-initializer

I know that virtual functions should not be called either directly or indirectly in a constructor, but this code runs fine.
Is what I have here safe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    A (const std::string& name) {std::cout << name << std::endl;}
    virtual std::string tag() const = 0;
};

struct B: A {
    B() : A (tag()) {}
    virtual std::string tag() const override {return "B";}
};

int main() {
    B b; // Output gives "B\n"
}
```

If not, would the following (based on a comment) be a correct workaround?

```
// Replacement for class B:

struct B: A {
    B() : A (name()) {}
    virtual std::string tag() const override {return name();}
private:
    static std::string name() {return "B";}  // use static function
};
```

Comment: "I know that virtual functions should not be called either directly or indirectly in a constructor"... That's a new one...

Comment: @ Deduplicator.  Going by your comment, I've written a different version above. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Deduplicator since when is it UB?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Reinstated and expanded comment: It's UB to call the virtual function there in the ctor-initializer, because the standard says so in 12.6.2 (14).

Comment: @Deduplicator Touché. Specifically, it's UB only because the bases haven't completed initialisation yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoking virtual members in the constructor and/or destructor is generally ok.

It's a different game in the ctor initializer though, before all bases are initialized:

> #### 12.6.2 Initializing bases and members `[class.base.init]`
>
> [...]
>   14 Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be called for an object under construction.
>   Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or of a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7). However, if these operations are performed in a **ctor-initializer** (or in a function called directly or indirectly from a ctor-initializer) **before all the mem-initializers for base classes have completed, the result of the operation is undefined.**

Comment: Ok, this convinces me to go with my second design, using your recommendation of static function redirection.

Comment: @prestokeys: Yes, call the static function directly.

Comment: Doesn't the final sentence just refer to typeid and dynamic_cast? And how can a ctor-initialiser possibly execute before the mem-initialisers of the base classes?

Comment: @EJP:  `MyClass() :MyBase(dynamic_cast<MyBase*>(this)) {}` and similar.

Comment: @MooingDuck No virtual function call there.

Comment: @EJP: It can execute if you explicitly specify base class initializer in the ctor initializer list. E.g. exactly as it is in the OP's original code sample. Since virtual function call `tag()` is used as an argument for base class initializer (in ctor initializer list), this virtual function will have to be called *before* base class initializer will have a chance to complete. Which is probably exactly what the above quote is intended to refer to.